# Android Intent broadcast from am broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent

Can anyone help with this code:

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MULTI_MODE_CHANGED ");
localIntent.putExtra("MULTI_MODE", paramString);
mContext.sendBroadcast(localIntent);
```

I am trying to understand how to broadcast the same intent from am broadcast from shell.
`mContext` is set to null at the beginning but on the `onCreate` function, this is displayed:
`mContext = this;`

This is in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<receiver android:name="HiddenmenuBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE"/>
        <data android:host="LTEMODE" android:scheme="android_secret_code"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I am not sure, but you are sending broadcast with intent android.intent.action.MULTI_MODE_CHANGED and receiver is registered for android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE.